# Touchpad synaptic misbehavior

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a DELL with a buttonless touchpad and I want to ask what can I do in order to get the touchpad button zone to work like a physical button, because I'm used to touchpads like that, and I have noticed that on Windows O.S. it behaves like that, you can lay a finger at the marked bottom zone and freely use another to move the cursor on the screen. I use Gnome and I installed gnome tweak tool and made the following procedure:

> Opened `gnome-tweak-tool` → *Keyboard and Mouse* → *Touchpad* → *Click Method* = Areas

By doing so, I've accomplished the desirable behavior, but when I installed KDE for testing purposes, it messed up the touchpad, and I got scroll when I try to lay a finger on the bottom part of the touchpad, and use another to move cursor.

That's my configurations with `xinput`:

```
Device 'DLL0651:00 06CB:2985':
Device Enabled (136):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (138): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (268): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (272):  82, 1967, 62, 1087
Synaptics Finger (273): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (274):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (275):   103
Synaptics Tap Durations (276):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (277):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (278):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (279):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (280):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (281): -46, -46
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (282): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (283):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (284): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.085251, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (285):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (286):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (287):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (288): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (289):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (290): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (291):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (292): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (293):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (294): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (295):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (296): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (297):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (298): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Grab Event Device (299):  0
Synaptics Gestures (300):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (301):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (302): 20, 20
Synaptics Area (303):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (304):  1024, 0, 941, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (305): 11, 11
Device Product ID (260):    1739, 10629
Device Node (259):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

That's it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run Lubuntu on a Toshiba Satellite with a synaptics touchpad. I had some problems with it just randomly clicking on buttons and such. Some updates came around and screwed it up after it would work. Final working solution was reload drivers - older versions - and disabled some convenience functions.

Comment: please include instruction as well